# Problematic AWS CLI within EC2 - Could Not Connect to EndPoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cli, aws-security-group

AWS CLI is problematic from within an EC2 instance.
I am on an EC2 Instance via Putty as well as Windows PowerShell (at different times). Command is: aws ec2 describe-instances

Result & error is:

Hanging and Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

The AWS CLI command is OK and correctly replies w json output when the CLI command executed from my *local windows command prompt.*

'aws configure' seems OK with the region is us-east-1

The EC2 instance can ping 8.8.8.8 as well as another instance (in same VPC, SubNet, region, etc) with a public IP.

I think I allowed everything open in the Security Groups (for troubleshooting purposes):
[img of the security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bioN7.png)

Network ACLs also left alone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TONpc.png)

These are new and blank EC2 instances.  To also note: 'sudo yum update' also returns an error of:
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 5515 milliseconds')

Thought I have all connections open (for sake of troubleshooting). Possible clue: Read elsewhere that *my internet connection* has to be "legit." I am using a free hotel wifi.  But this doesnt make sense as its the EC2 doing the pinging, and my windows cmd can return results.

Thank you very much.
-Martin

Comment: Does your security group and/ or network ACL allow outbound traffic on port 443 ?

Comment: Further clue:  EC2 instance *can* ping IP addresses, but cannot ping FQDNs. So can ping 8.8.8.8 but not http://www.cnn.com  (timing out). Assuming the inability to hit an AWS endpoint is bec of FQDN.

Comment: so your instance is unable to resolve domain names to IP addresses.

Comment: That was it.  Had an old (junk) DHCP Option set that was interfering with Search Options.  Deleted old DHCP Option Set and all works.  Thank you.